# How do I use dependency injection and a jwt token with refit?

Tags: refit

I cannot find any examples of using dependency injection with Refit and passing in Jwts per request... or any other way that's not a single hard-coded value in the `program.cs` file

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRefitClient<IMyApi>()
.ConfigureHttpClient(c => {
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(_appSettings.ApiBaseUrl);
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
});
```

Refit interface

```
public interface IMyApi
{
    [Get("/login/")]
    Task<LoginResponse> Login(LoginRequest request);

    [Headers("Authorization: Bearer")]
    [Get("/MyEntity/")]
    Task<GetMyEntityResponse> Authenticate(GetMyEntityRequest request);
}
```

mvc controller

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMyApi _myApiClient;

    public TestController(IMyApi myApiClient)
    {
        _myApiClient = myApiClient;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        // Login and get Jwt token
        var loginResponse = await _myApiClient.Login();
        var myJwtToken = loginResponse.Token;
    
        // Get a 401 unauthorized here.. how do I pass in my Jwt token?
        var myEntity = await _myApiClient.GetMyEntity();

        return View(myEntity);
    }
}
```